# predict revision number before commit

Tags: svn, version, revision

Is it possible to predict revision number before commit?

It would be useful. I want to write revision number in changelog and commit it together with changes it's providing.

I know the number can be changed before my commit reaches repo but still it would be nice to know.

I'm writing my changelogs in plain text using rst formatting

more info: every commit message contains issue id, this is also appears in title of changelog.

**please stick to the question** 
 I'm asking if this is possible and how, not if this would make sense or anything else.

Why do I need this? I need this information that person, who deploys application would know in which revision those changes appear so he may update production server accordingly. He reads changelog anyway because it contains information about changes in database and other important stuff. It just would be a little bit easier if he musn't use `blame` to see which revision this entry belongs to.

Comment: What if someone else commits as you write the changelog?

Comment: It's probably possible, but never 100% reliable (somebody else could commit at the same time, for example). You need to give more information about what you are using to write the change log, which platform you're one etc.

Comment: @Pekka, I'm writing my changelogs in plain text using rst formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking to the question as requested: **No, this is not possible - not reliably, anyway.**

This is a chicken-and-egg problem: the revision number is assigned only when the commit succeeds, so you can't include it in the commit itself.

You can go ahead and *guess* "all right, we're on revision 12345, so next revision is 12346", but while you're guessing (even if it takes you a few milliseconds), I've succesfully commited a revision, and you guess wrong. Not by evil intent, mind you - I have no mechanism to know that you're about to commit.

Comment: At last strigt answer. Based on what @Piskvor says the only option is to append revision version to changelog in next commit.

Comment: @seler: But that would leave you with two revisions per commit (at best): the actual files, and the no-content revision with the previous revision number, right? Not to mention the danger of one commit triggering another and that triggering another - a textbook example of [laser mode](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/software-laser.html).

Comment: yes, that would leave me with two commits one with code, one with update to changelog. thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid and the reason of posting my question.

Answer (score 7):

A bit hacky but this should work on Linux: if you type at the prompt

```
svn up
```

The last line of the answer will be

```
At revision 42.
```

or

```
Updated to revision 42.
```

Where 42 is the revision number of the last commit on the whole svn server. So the next commit will be this one + 1. You can get it, with this command:

```
svn up | sed -ne 's/revision //p' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

If you're fast enough, you can **hope** no one will commit before you. If you have a working copy of the **root** of the svn server, you could lock it to prevent any commit and unlock it at the end:

```
svn lock rootdir
svn unlock rootdir
```

Comment: Your first stackoverflow answer? Welcome! What's very good is that you formatted your answer properly, it shows attention to detail.

Answer (score 3):

This approach **avoids interact with working copy** repo.

Directly query the SVN server with info command at top `root` directory of your repository:

```
svn info https://myserver/svn/my-project-root-dir
```

this will show something like:

```
Path: my-project-root-dir
URL: https://myserver/svn/my-project-root-dir
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: https://myserver/svn/my-project-root-dir
Repository UUID: 7f430767-c695-4424-a1c3-24180d67394b
Revision: 2255
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: joe
Last Changed Rev: 2255
Last Changed Date: 2016-11-13 20:22:33 +0100
```

so your "next" svn revision will be 2256.

Let's say:

```
$ svn info https://myserver/svn/my-project-root-dir | grep "Last Changed Rev: " | awk -F ": " -- '{ print $2 }'
2255
```

or get an automatic increment (bash):

```
$ R=$(svn info https://myserver/svn/my-project-root-dir  | grep "Last Changed Rev: " | awk -F ": " -- '{ print $2 }'); let R+=1; echo $R
2256
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the revision number for issue tracking or for some feature tracking, then you can use the post-commit hook to send an email to your issue/feature tracking server with the entire commit log message. The issue tracker can then parse this email and add the contents to the respective issue. The key is the issue number against which you are making the commit. In other words, you need to specify the issue number in your commit log message in a specific format(s) so that the issue tracker can look for it while parsing the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pre-commit hook, where you write the changelog and you use a special tag to denote an area of the changelog that svn can modify accordingly.

More info [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) and [here](http://chestofbooks.com/computers/revision-control/subversion-svn/svnlook-Reposadmin-Maint-Tk-svnlook.html)

Comment: Never modify things during a hook script of the orignal source cause that will break the synchronization of client/server.

Comment: Maybe a force update after the commit to get the actual file? Can that be done with a post commit hook?

Comment: No, cause a hook script runs on the server whereas the working copy is on the client so no choice.

Comment: I was thinking about the changelog as a revision message, that's why I proposed it. That way it would work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to write in the change log the issue number which you are solving and the issue tracking system will automatically scan svn repository and make the association between the issue and the revision number (Many issue tracking do that, JIRA, Redmine, Trac etc.). 
Furthermore using the revision number is not reliable, cause during writing the changelog someone else can do a commit before (already mentioned).

Comment: issue number is already in changelog. please answer my question which is if this is possible otherwise do not post non related answers.